# On April 1, have the "Papers, Please" music playing while we're in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, april-fools

[The idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbBB1j5qAFs) got ahold of me and I haven't been able to get it out of my head for a while (much like the music), so I figure hey, maybe it'll be worth considering.

Comment: just one question, Why?

Comment: Don't forget the explosion and evacuating from the review queue after reviewing enough posts.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4vjVetZPpM.

Comment: Glory to Arstotzka.

Comment: Papers, Please is a genius game, but it's still way too niche to make a proper joke out of it that won't wooosh over the heads of a good many people. I give you bonus points for trying to add a bit of fun to reviewing though ;)

Comment: We hate fun. No.

Comment: Just when I think I'm a player, I find I'm just an NPC, with bad paperwork.

Comment: @jthill next! Admission is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please no.

Webpages that aren't meant to play music [shouldn't](https://moz.com/blog/how-to-convince-a-client-their-site-doesnt-need-music) [play](https://www.argondesign.com.au/digital/why-adding-background-music-on-your-site-is-a-bad-idea/) [music](https://www.zigpress.com/2009/10/30/10-reasons-websites-should-not-play-music/).

<sub>Disclaimer: [I hate fun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lHVF.png).</sub>

Comment: Would it even make sense to announce the "joke" in advance? Not getting this.

Comment: I think that question is better directed at this question than this answer, @yivi :D

Answer (score 1):

**[Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)** (Jeff Atwood, 2010)

> I think some members of the community have gotten the idea that Stack Overflow is strictly business — unless your question fits our rules exactly to a T, it is absolutely disallowed. That, **here on Stack Overflow, we hate “fun”.**

Glory to Arstotzka.

Comment: And go [arskickers](https://papersplease.fandom.com/wiki/Arstotzka_Arskickers_pennant)!